# Featured questions feature cut text

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

It seems that some featured questions also show their last line as cut, while others do not.

See image:

> [image]

I assume there is a set number of line used, so shouldn't each featured question section have a fixed height so that it always fit in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.  The height of the title line was being calculated with Truncate Tail rather than Word Wrap line break mode.

Comment: Always good to see new employees around... better mention this in your profile though otherwise people will think you're "just" another moderator. :-)